# How to hide URL extensions to prevent accessing the page/s

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am developing a game with react which has a lot of url path for the stages of the game. I want to hide the URL extension to prevent access to the other page/s or prevent the user on typing the path to the next level of the game.

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom"; 
...

<Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <section className="container">
            <Alert />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/scene1" component={Scene1} />
              <MemoryRouter>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/garbage" component={Garbage} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/scene3" component={Scene3} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/portal1scene3" component={Portal1Scene3} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/scene4" component={Scene4} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/scene6" component={Scene6} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/scene5" component={Scene5} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/scene2" component={Scene2} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/portal1scene2" component={Portal1Scene2} />
              </MemoryRouter>
            </Switch>
          </section>
        </Fragment>
</Router>
```

As you may have seen in my App.js file, I already tried  but after completing Scene1, I cant access the next scene or the next path.

Is it wrong to use MemoryRouter?

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditionals to make access restrictions.
Something like this

```
let isScene1Finished = false;
let isScene2Finished = false;
```

Then in your switch

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />

  <PrivateRoute exact path="/scene1" component={Scene1} />

  // if scene 1 is done, make scene 2 available
  {!!isScene1Finished && <PrivateRoute exact path="/scene2" component={Scene2} />}

  // if scene 2 is done, make scene 3 available
  {!!isScene2Finished && <PrivateRoute exact path="/scene3" component={Scene2} />}

  // and so on ...
</Switch>
```

Note: The inline comments are only there for an explanation. You need to remove them for it to work.

Also notice the `!!`, its there to make sure that the variable to converted to a boolean value.